# Assingn TRUE value to a funcion in VB

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, vb.net-to-c#

The VB code below assigns True value assign to the function.  But when I convert to C#, I am getting an error like we can not assign True to a method.  How can I assign true to the method in C#.  This is my VB code:

```
Private Function KeyOK(ByVal sKey As String) As Boolea

    KeyOK = True
    sKey = Trim(sKey)

    If Len(sKey) <> KEY_LENGTH Then
        KeyOK = False
        Exit Function
```

Answer (score 5):

The equivalent in C# is the **return** keyword.  So, instead of *KeyOK = false*, you'd just write:

```
return false;
```

Here's an equivalent C# function:

```
private bool KeyOK(string sKey) 
{
    bool result = true;
    sKey = (sKey ?? "").Trim();
    if (sKey.Length != KEY_LENGTH)
        result = false;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is also the preferred method in VB as well.  The assignment of the function name is a holdover from vb6 and earlier.

Comment: Just calling return is not the equivalent, since it will immediately exit the method.  Assigning the value to the function name in VB does not immediately exit the function.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway that's a good point.  I don't think there's really an equivalent in C#, is there, other than creating a new private variable to hold the return value?

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of style/taste, but I would leave out the intermediates

```
private bool KeyOK(string key)  { 
    return (key ?? "").Trim().Length == KEY_LENGTH;
}
```

or simply

```
private bool KeyOK(string key)  { 
    return key.Trim().Length == KEY_LENGTH;
}
```

if you are happy that key will never be null.

(sticking my nose in un-necessarily) 
Alan.